# How to fix 'Unsupported tag api' error in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I’m trying to send informations between 2 smartphones with NFC technology with the usage of react native but when the tag is sent, I get the error: Unsupported tag api. But I don’t know how to correct this issue. Can someone helps me please?

I tried with multiples phones but nothing changed. I’m using Ndef technology for that. I write the tag with writeNdefMessage part of NfcManager. I think that I imported all the things needed…I’no idea about the origin of the problem!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import NfcManager, { NfcEvents, NfcTech, Ndef } from 'react-native-nfc-manager';

function App() {
  const [hasNfc, setHasNFC] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIsSupported = async () => {
      const deviceIsSupported = await NfcManager.isSupported()

      setHasNFC(deviceIsSupported)
      if (deviceIsSupported) {
        await NfcManager.start()
      }
    }

    checkIsSupported()
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleTagDiscovered = async (tag) => {
      console.log('tag found', tag);
    };

    NfcManager.start();
    NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, handleTagDiscovered);

    return () => {
      NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, null);
    };
  }, []);


  const readTag = async () => {
    await NfcManager.registerTagEvent();
  }

  const writeNFC = async () => {
    try {
      await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef);
      const bytes = Ndef.encodeMessage([Ndef.uriRecord('${workspaceFolder}/Appli_NFC_TPE/citroen ami.png')]);

      if (bytes) {
        await NfcManager.ndefHandler.writeNdefMessage(bytes);
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.warn(ex);
    } finally {
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    }
  };

  if (hasNfc === null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!hasNfc) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
        <Text>NFC not supported</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, styles.btnScan]} onPress={readTag}>
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Scan Tag</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.btn, styles.btnWrite]} onPress={writeNFC}>
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Write Tag</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  btn: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnScan: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  btnWrite: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide the code to reproduce the issue

Comment: Yep sorry, I've just done that !